# cd + bash completion script

Tags: ubuntu, bash, command-line-interface

I have web projects in `/var/www/projects/some/long/path/strange-project-name`

Now I want to type in terminal:

```
webs str{TAB}
```

It should autocomplete to the `webs strange-project-name` (basing on `ls /var/www/projects/some/long/path/`) and after executing the command, the `pwd` should point to project path. Kind of smart `cd strange-project-name` with autocomplete

How would you implement this feature? Some smart alias? Function in `.bashrc`? Script?

Some smart alias?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need a two-parter. **One**, a completion script:

```
_webs() {
    local cur prev projdir=/var/www/projects/some/long/path

    COMPREPLY=()
    cur=$(_get_cword)
    prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}

    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '$( command ls "$projdir/$cur*" | sed "s|$projdir/||")' -- '' ) )
}
complete -F _webs webs
```

`_get_cword` depends on the bash-completions package being installed. If you don't have it then change the line:

```
cur=$(_get_cword)
```

to:

```
cur=${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}
```

**Two**, a function:

```
webs () {
    local projdir=/var/www/projects/some/long/path
    cd "$projdir"
    do_something_ "$@"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. With this as a start I managed to do what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you need...

in terminal...

```
sudo vim /etc/inputrc
```

find this rows and uncomment it:

```
# alternate mappings for “page up” and “page down” to search the history

#”\e[5~”: history-search-backward

#”\e[6~”: history-search-forward
```

now you can auto complete commands from your history with page up/down

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom bash autocompletion script for that. Take a look at `/etc/bash_completion.d` directory and its numerous examples. Then create a file called `webs` to that directory and adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this is exactly what [Lightning](https://github.com/cldwalker/lightning) was created for. It's a Ruby project, so this isn't a good answer if using Bash is a goal in itself.